# Why doesn't assignment to variable y work in a Ruby block?

Tags: ruby

I assign the value "1" to the variables x and y outside the block, and then I reference the variable x of the same name outside the block in a block, so x is both 1.

Next, I assign the value of x to y in the block. In theory, y should also be 1, but the most trusted result is **x = 1, y = 3**.

Please tell me why.

```
x = 1               
y = 1               
ary = [1, 2, 3]

ary.each do |x|     
    y = x           
end

p [x, y]
```

Comment: This is known as [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) – you're creating a new `x` for the block.

Comment: I'm really curious WHY you're asking this question.  What is your goal here?  What is the purpose of iterating through an array if you're expecting the results to be based entirely on unrelated local variables.

Comment: for practice and learning

Comment: for practice and learning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of confusion  here is so-called shadowing. You have two local variables called `x` here, but only one called `y`. The second `x` variable is shadowing the first one - meaning that any attempt to access or assign to the first variable is doomed to fail.

When you do `ary.each do |x|`, you are creating new variable, which has nothing (except for the name) to do with the variable `x` you have created in the outer scope.

`y` on the other hand is not shadowed and the loop binding is accessing (and assigning to) the variable defined in the parent scope. Unfortunately there is no way (at least that I am aware of) of explicit local variable creation like `var`/`let`/`const` in javascript.

In short, your code executes as follow:

```
x = 1               
y = 1               
ary = [1, 2, 3]

ary.each do |x2|     
  y = x2         
end

p [x, y]
```

So in fact, assignment to y works just as expected. You assign it value of 1 before the block, and then you assign 3 more times within the block. The last assignment is `y=3` so that's its final value.

BEWARE, THE HACK:

Well there actually is a way of forcing the local variable creation, and it is to add an extra yielding argument to each block. **This should never be done in the actual code**, and I only present it for completeness. You should actually avoid any variable shadowing whenever possible.

```
x = y = 1
ary = [2,3,4]

ary.each do |x, y| # this creates new local variables x and y, y is always set to nil for each iteration.
  y = x # y here is a shadowing variable, not the y of the parent scope
  puts [x,y].inspect
end

puts [x,y].inspect

# OUTPUTS:
  
[2, 2]
[3, 3]
[4, 4]
[1, 1]
```

Comment: In this case, where does the last ```p [x, y] ``` print out x and y?

Comment: In your example, the value of ary is continuously passed into the block's ```x``` , so ```y``` is always ```nil``` until x is assigned to y, right?

Comment: `y` is `nil` within the block - but `y` within the block is not the same as `y` outside of the block. I'll update the answer to make this more clear.

Comment: @steenslag - I am not sure if there's a typo in your comment, but the above gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you, I know why y is 3. But why is x still 1?

Comment: @BroiSatse my comment was still inaccurate, I deleted is. I added ans answer which is accuate (I hope).

Answer (score 3):

Block parameters (the stuff between the pipes like `|x,y|`) are local to the block. But pre-existing variables are not.

```
total = 0
[1,5].each{|n| total += n} #works because total starts out as 0
puts total # => 6
```

If you want a block-local `total` then follow the parameters by a semicolon and a comma-separated list of variables

```
total = 0
[1,5].each{|n; total, _unused| total += n} #Error because total is nil
puts total
```

Comment: I can't tell the difference between the two variables with or without ";"

Comment: In the first sample  the variable `total` is defined outside the block, and visible inside it. `n` is a block parameter and only visible inside the block, not outside it. In the second sample, `total` is a block-local variable, completely independent from the `total` outside the block.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are redefining `x` in the scope of the block. `ary.each do |x|` does this.

Comment: What is refining x? What is the process?

Comment: I assume this is a typo and the answer should say "redefining".

Comment: "refining" has [specific meaning](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) in Ruby.

Comment: @idmean correct it was a typo.